# PS Script to move a folder based on its name to another folder based on that name

Tags: powershell, move

Im looking to move a folder or folders with the name S0 in the name to another folder with the word shows in it.

Paths are

Source is S:\ -= Downloads\
              Destination is S:\ -= Shows\

Comment: Q: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Those paths don't make much sense. What does `S:-=` mean?

Comment: Sorry, was updating it on my phone. S:\ is the drive letter, helps if I added the \

Source is S:\-= Downloads\ 
Destination is S:\-= Shows\

Comment: I havent tried any PS scripting yet....

Comment: Im new to PS so Im not even sure where to start